# Mysql - How to insert sorted data into a single row

Tags: mysql, insert

Ok I need to select an ordered set of data from one table and insert into a single entry in another table within a stored procedure. Basically I need an ordered Transpose.

Current method - select the data in a cursor and then create a string for the insert concatenating the data in a string.  Then executing that insert string.
Problem is the strings (s) have ' and " in them which is causing the execute to fail.

Here is the select - SELECT IDA,s FROM A ORDER BY val desc limit 3;

Now I need to put that in a row in B...

```
Table A 
IDA - int
val- int
s- string

Table B
IDB - int
IDA1 - int
sA1 - string;
IDA2 - int
sA2 - string;
IDA3 - int
sA3 - string
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: Previous method didn't work so I have scrapped that code.  It is just how would you put the top 3 (val) rows into a single insert in Table B?

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided, this example can help:

```
SET @mystring := 'abc\'def"ghi"';
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO tablab (sA1) values (\'', REPLACE(@mystring, X'27', CONCAT('\\', X'27')), '\');');
```

Result:

```
INSERT INTO tablab (sA1) values ('abc\'def"ghi"');
```